# C++ Stop thread from function

Tags: c++

How can I stop a thread from the function called?

```
void foo()
{
    cout << hello << endl;
    t.join(); //Is it possible to do something like this?
}

int main()
{
    thread t(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to pass itself as argument like this: thread t(foo, t) but it gave me an error.

Comment: How about `thread *t; t = new thread(foo, t);`? I'm not sure about `t->join();` part, that's no way to stop a thread

Comment: Just let `foo()` return to terminate that thread....  That said, the caller needs to do the join if you want to avoid process termination before the thread's got that far.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you want, you can exit the thread prematurely by just returning from the function you are executing. Joining yourself cannot work, because join means wait until the thread finished but that can't happen before the join is complete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thread will terminate automatically when `foo()` returns. The `join` is pointless - it would never return. join() would simply wait for that thread to terminate - which will never happen in this case.

If you need to terminate a thread from another thread (e.g. your main thread), you need to communicate that yourself. Either via a flag (and a mutex/condition variable) or e.g. a pipe, if you use `select()`, `poll()` or similiar functions.